# Update Array using $in and $addtoSet Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-update

I am using `$in` and `$addToSet` to update an array in my collections. Say I have this kind of my documents.

```
{ 
    _id: objectId(1), //this is just an example id
    names: ['harry', 'hermione']
},
{
    _id: objectId(2),
    names: ['ron']
},
{
    _id: objectId(3),
    names: ['dumbledoor']
}
```

I want to update all of this documents so I have an array of ids

```
var arr_ids = [1, 2];
```

and use the array `map` like this.

```
var ids = arr_ids.map(function(id) { return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id); });
```

To update all the documents in my collections.

```
db.update( { _id: { $in: ids } }, { $addToSet: { name : 'draco' } }, 
    function(err, results) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      console.log(results);
    }
);
```

I use the `$in` and `$addToSet` and it works and updates the document but it only updates the last document.

```
{ 
    _id: objectId(1), //this is just an example id
    names: ['harry', 'hermione']
},
{
    _id: objectId(2),
    names: ['ron', 'draco'] // it only update this document.
},
{
    _id: objectId(3),
    names: ['dumbledoor']
}
```

I don't know why. I don't want to create a for loop just to update it individually, but it seems to me that's my last resort. Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `multi: true` like so

```
db.update( /*query*/, { $addToSet: { names : 'draco' } }, {multi:  true} ...
```

See [multi-parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) and [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-multi) for the documentation for it